# How to reverse the digits INSIDE of an element in an array in C#

Tags: c#

here is what I try to accomplish in C#:
Before reverse:

```
new string[] initial={"1011","001"};
```

After reverse:

```
new string[] final={"1101","100"};
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `Array.Reverse(initial);`

Comment: The same result can be achieved by reversing the array and by reversing digits inside each string, because the strings are mirror images of each other.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You might want to choose different strings, such as `{ "abcd", "1234" }`. Also note that strings are not arrays.

Comment: Of course, you don't really need to do that, unless your passing it off to an api call or some dependency because you can just reverse your acess logic.  E.g. say you are looping through them, just loop through them backwards.  Say you want to get the 3rd reversed element just do (Array.Count - 3).

Comment: This question is kind of misleading. What you really want to know is how to  reverse a string, which has been asked many times before.

Comment: @rossipedia the tittle says: How to reverse the elements INSIDE of an element in an array in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because it is unclear that you want to reverse the array, or reverse all of it's elements. i have covered both.

if you want to reverse all elements inside array:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] x = new string[] {"1100", "2200"};
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                x[i] = new string(x[i].Reverse().ToArray());
            }
            foreach (string s in x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result: "0011", "0022"

if you want to reverse the array to show from last to the first:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] x = new string[] {"1100", "2200"};
            Array.Reverse(x);
            foreach (string s in x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result:  "2200" ,"1100"

Answer (score 3):

If you have an enumerable `original` of enumerables, and you want to project it into an enumerable that contains the same members, only reversed, you can use:

```
var reversedMembers = original.Select(Enumerable.Reverse);
```

If you are specifically concerned with string arrays, you can do this:

```
var original = new string[] { "1011","1101" };
var reversed = original.Select(s => String.Concat(s.Reverse())).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know the `string` type represents a ***sequence of Unicode characters***. And we can select reversed sequence of `string` object with the help of `IEnumerable.Reverse()` method. And  the last remaining thing is to use `Select()` method to project each element of an array into a new form:

```
 var final = initial.Select(x => new string(x.Reverse().ToArray())).ToArray();
```

The inputs: *35*, *001*, *abcd*
The output: *53*, *100*, *dcba*

Answer (score 0):

you can use Reverse method of array like this.

Array.Reverse(array_name);

for more details see this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In place reverse:

```
Array.Reverse(array);
```

Return new array:

```
var reversed = array.Reverse().ToArray();
```